# Set Voice to Text output to text box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am a n00b so I was using this method to convert voice to text:

```
private async void STT_Freeform(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
SpeechRecognizerUI speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
speechRecognizer.Settings.ExampleText = "Fine thanks";
speechRecognizer.Settings.ListenText = "How's it goin', eh?";
speechRecognizer.Settings.ReadoutEnabled = true;
speechRecognizer.Settings.ShowConfirmation = true;
SpeechRecognitionUIResult result = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
if (result.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
{
    MessageBox.Show(result.RecognitionResult.Text);
}
```

}

But I want to change it so that whatever its spoken, it gets pasted onto the TextBox within the app

Comment: It's not clear where you're having troubles. Why not just put the results in a `TextBox` rather than showing a `MessageBox`? `txtResults.Text = result.RecognitionResult.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the result text to the textbox, for example:

```
public partial class TestPage : PhoneApplicationPage  
    {  
        SpeechRecognizerUI speechRecognizer;  

        // Constructor  
        public TestPage ()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  

            this.speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizerUI();  
        }  

        private async void STT_Freeform(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            this.speechRecognizer.Recognizer.Grammars.Clear();  

            // Use the short message dictation grammar with the speech recognizer.  
            this.speechRecognizer.Recognizer.Grammars.AddGrammarFromPredefinedType("message", SpeechPredefinedGrammar.Dictation);  

            await this.speechRecognizer.Recognizer.PreloadGrammarsAsync();  

            try  
            {  
                // Use the built-in UI to prompt the user and get the result.  
                SpeechRecognitionUIResult recognitionResult = await this.speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();  

                if (recognitionResult.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)  
                {  
                    // Output the speech recognition result.  
                    txtDictationResult.Text = "You said: " + recognitionResult.RecognitionResult.Text;  
                }  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
            }  
        }  

        private async void btnWebSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            this.speechRecognizer.Recognizer.Grammars.Clear();  

            this.speechRecognizer.Recognizer.Grammars.AddGrammarFromPredefinedType("search", SpeechPredefinedGrammar.WebSearch);  

            await this.speechRecognizer.Recognizer.PreloadGrammarsAsync();  

            try  
            {  
                // Use the built-in UI to prompt the user and get the result.  
                SpeechRecognitionUIResult recognitionResult = await this.speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();  

                if (recognitionResult.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)  
                {  
                    // Output the speech recognition result.  
                    this.txtWebSearchResult.Text = "You said: " + recognitionResult.RecognitionResult.Text;  
                }  

            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
            }  
        }  
    }
```